# FAB above the layout for API>=21 and below the layout for API<21

Tags: android, android-layout

its showing the FAB below the layout for API<21 while for 21+ its shows above the layout

here is the [link](https://github.com/HarshitShihora7/first/blob/master/activity_categories.xml) for code(could not post here because no. of characters increases). along with the png's for [link](https://github.com/HarshitShihora7/first) how to make it work for API<21

Comment: I am not hearing a question...

Comment: @Harish how to make that work for API<21

Comment: edit your question and put the comment inside your question

Comment: @HARSHITSHIHORA You can [edit] the question by using the link under the question. It’s mentioned in the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) page. Make sure to read that.

Comment: You should put your `FloatingActionButton` after `ScrollView`